# ReactJS not re-rendering component when setting global state in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
for (const method of methodsToRun) {
    let result = /*runStuff*/;
    results.push(...(JSON.parse(result)));
    setGlobalState('dataOutput', results);
}
```

I have this loop that runs an algorithm on every iteration (each iteration may take a few seconds to complete). I need the component depending on the '*dataOuput*' global state to re-render when updated on every iteration, but it updates only when the loop is done. I guess this is due to the fact that JS is single-threaded and the re-rendering gets queued, any workarounds to ensure re-rendering in every iteration of the loop?

PS: I'm using *react-hooks-global-state* to manage the global state, not Redux

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use setTimeout. All setState events in 1ms in react occur same time

Comment: Already tried this but no luck, plus "All setState events in 1ms in react occur same time" is not the issue here